# Redirecting to www. breaks localhost

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have been searching all over the internet and trying all sorts of things to resolve my issue but no luck unfortunately.

My issues is that I have created a .htaccess file in order to redirect a website from [DOMAIN].co.uk   to   www.[DOMAIN].co.uk     Here is the .htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.|localhost$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

This had worked brilliantly on the external site, but unfortunately I used this htaccess in my localhost(oops) and now my localhost redirects to www.localhost with this error..

```
Oops! Google Chrome could not find www.localhost
```

How can I stop my localhost redirecting to the www.localhost?

Note the shown .htaccess file is not the one used do do the redirect in the first place. It is an amended one which I thought would fix the problem. The original .htaccess didn't state anything about localhost.

I have attempted to change my .htaccess to:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.|localhost$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Which to me looks like its saying, if the URL has localhost or www. then change it to non www.
No luck

Thanks!

Update:
I have tried this bit of code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Both on the external server and localhost. The external server now points to non www. but the localhost still goes to www.

UPDATE problem solved.
Merely needed to clear browser cache.

Comment: Your localhost isn't a website, so changing localhost to www.localhost isn't going to work.

Comment: That is the point. It has changed the localhost to www.localhost as I had my .htaccess file in my localhost folder(oops). I need it to not go to www.localhost but I cannot seem to achieve this. I will tweak main post to make that clearer

Comment: Your current condition is true if the host *either* does not start with `www.` *or* does not end with `localhost`. Think about that.

Comment: I only started learning .htaccess yesterday so unfortunately this is a learning curve. I have tried tweaking the lines(which i will include in the original post) but no luck

Comment: Your first rule should work, try in a new browser.

Comment: Ah! Brilliant. It is the browser.. I do wonder why Google Chrome is doing this as it hasn't done this before and only done it after messing with .htaccess. Does Chrome get changed somehow with the .htaccess? Anyway thanks Anu!

Comment: It is due to use if 301 that chromse is caching it.